# .htaccess RewriteRule with multiple GET variables?

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I saw a lot of similar questions, but I couldn't solve this problem with their answers..

I'm trying to do a URL Rewrite by converting

```
http://example.com/myfile.php?var1=42&var2=aString
```

to

```
http://example.com/mydir/42/aString
```

I tried the following `RewriteRule` 's (one by one) :

- `RewriteRule    ^mydir/([0-9]+)/(.*)/(.*)$    myfile.php?var1=$1&var2=$2    [NC,L]`
- `RewriteRule    ^mydir/([0-9]+)/(.+)/(.+)$    myfile.php?var1=$1&var2=$2    [NC,L]`
- `RewriteRule    ^mydir/([0-9]+)/?$/?$    myfile.php?var1=$1&var2=$2    [NC,L]`

I couldn't get them work..
What am I doing wrong? and how can I make it work?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 3 groups but only two parameters, try with two groups

```
RewriteRule ^mydir/([0-9]+)/(.*)$ myfile.php?var1=$1&var2=$2 [NC,L]
```